# How to disable a button based on clicking an odd or even button in a list

Tags: jquery

I have many buttons in a list and two additional ones: one with the class odd and one with the class even. If I click an odd button in the list I want to disable the button with class odd and vice versa.

```
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>5</button>

    <button id="odd">odd</button> 
    <button id="even">even</button>


$("#odd").click(function() { 

        $("buttons").text().disabled;
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
var oddBtn  = $('#odd'),
    evenBtn = $('#even'),
    disable = function(){
        var type = $(this).is(oddBtn) ? 1 : 0;
        $('button').attr('disabled', false).filter(function(){
            return +$(this).text() % 2 == type;
        }).attr('disabled', true);
    };

oddBtn.on('click', disable);
evenBtn.on('click', disable);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LCBj/

Answer (score 1):

The javascript adds an event listener for the odd button and then loops through all buttons, checks that the text is a number and if odd adds the disabled property to it.

HTML

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>5</button>

<button id="odds">odd</button> 
<button id="even">even</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#odds").click(function() {
        $("button").each(function() {

            var buttonval = $(this).text()

            if(!isNaN(buttonval)) 
            {
                if(parseInt(buttonval) % 2 != 0) {
                     $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("#even").click(function() {
        $("button").each(function() {

            var buttonval = $(this).text()

            if(!isNaN(buttonval)) 
            {
                if(parseInt(buttonval) % 2 == 0) {
                     $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmv3m/5/

Comment: it doesn't conatian any class don't change dom structure

Comment: i ask button text odd to be disabled

Comment: well just don't add the even button listener then.

Comment: How can "text" be disabled anyway?

Comment: No, text contains odd number buttons should be disabled

Comment: Ok, updated my jQuery to check whether the text is a number and then disable if odd

Comment: Note: I have changed the id on the button to be "even" to match your edit in your first post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter`

```
$("#odd, #even").click(function() { 
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("button").attr("disabled",false);
  $("button").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text() % 2 == (id == "odd" ? 1 : 0))
  }).attr("disabled",true);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m7bu9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#odd").click(function() {
    $("button").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        if((val%2) == 1){
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });

});

$("#even").click(function() {
    $("button").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        if((val%2) == 0){
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3j7w8/)